# How to use boost asio for multiple udp connections?

Tags: boost-asio

In the application I am working on, hundreds of clients will connect to the server via UDP. The socket connection remains open for each client until the client decides to quit.

I downloaded boost's sample code for asynchronous udp server at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html.

From the code, a couple of things are not clear:

1. As each connection is made from the client, I would like to save the IP of the incoming client. However, from the code, it is not obvious where I can put this logic.
2. It seems this code can only serve one client at a time. In my case, there will be many concurrent connections and the socket must be kept alive for each connection. How do I extend this code? Regards.

Comment: There is really no such thing as a UDP connection. It really seems like you're trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

> As each connection is made from the client, I would like to save the IP of the incoming client. However, from the code, it is not obvious where I can put this logic.

This code has no notion of a connection. If you're writing code that knows what a connection is, then someplace it will decide whether or not each incoming datagram is part of an existing connection or establishing a new one. That's where you would put that logic.

> It seems this code can only serve one client at a time. In my case, there will be many concurrent connections and the socket must be kept alive for each connection.

You seem to be under the impression that the UDP socket is associated with a connection. This is not so. UDP knows nothing about connections, that's entirely a feature of your code. Since the UDP implementation has no idea about these connections, it will just give you all the datagrams it receives. There's no socket for each connection like there is with connection-oriented protocols like TCP.

If you need connections and for some reason still want to use a connectionless protocol like UDP, all the connection logic is your responsibility. You will have one socket and you will receive one datagram at a time, but can sustain any number of concurrent "connections" so long as you write code to support that.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is held in `remote_endpont_`
2. You need to convert the code, add multiple threads dispatching on the io_service and ensure that on handling a new packet, create a new client handler instance to deal with that...